# Faster way to "geocode" on unique ID?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, geocoding

I've inherited some scripts that (to my mind) "abuse" geocoding to position points based on a `LocationID` field.  As the name implies, this field is a unique ID that really doesn't need to be "fuzzy matched"; either it matches or it doesn't.  Besides that, using the geocoding tools for this process is painfully slow; some 5 minutes or more to geocode less than 100k records.

I've tried using joins, with not much luck:

- Joining the tables to the reference points with `AddJoin`: with `"KEEP_ALL"` results in *all* the points, some with no data; with `"KEEP_COMMON"` results in only matching points, but loses data where multiple rows have the same `LocationID`.
- Joining the points to the tables with `AddJoin` results in tables, not point features.
- Joining either way with `JoinField` is even slower than geocoding, and has the same issues as above.
- None of these methods produces a new feature class as geocoding does; that takes a `CopyFeatures` either before or after the join.  (`SpatialJoin` does, but it's out of the question since one input is a table....)

So, *is* there any faster way to do this using GP tools – if not, that might explain why it is the way it is – or should I look to a lower-level solution (`arcpy.da` or the like)?

(To clarify, the output I'm looking for is a point feature class:  each point has data from a row in the input table, but there may be multiple points in a given location.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about transferring points coordinates to table. You might use this process:

1. Add X and Y fields to points' table
2. Join above to TABLE using common field. Calculate similar field e.g. [XN]=Points!X
3. Export joined table to new one.
4. Create XY event table from output at step 4.
   Based on your Q you'll end up with duplicate points in some cases.

Comment: In fact the point features we're using to geocode come from a generated event layer, so maybe I could just have a separate join-and-make-event-layer for each table?  And yes, I expect duplicate points, but with different data.

Comment: Yes, it is likely you've got XY fields already in your point layer. Join by attribute is always a pain in ArcGIS with real life datasets, be ready to wait..

Comment: Well, it does work, so I'm accepting the answer.  Unfortunately it's really not much faster -- that join is killing me -- so I will stick with geocoding for now and just try tweaking the parameters some more.

Comment: As I mentioned f.calculator IS pain. arcpy.da cursor is far more superior, you start with creating dictionary on parent, then iterate through childs record with update cursor on x and y field. Search site

Comment: So you mean to cache the coordinates in Python instead of using a "true" join?  Can't believe that didn't even occur to me -- I'm already using a similar technique in another tool. *sigh*  Thanks again, I'll try it when I'm back in office.